# Can I pass regular expression pattern into url to send to server to process?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc

My situation is: I have two IIS site: A(file upload, use ASP.NET MVC), B(normal web site, use ASP.NET). B call A(in iframe, pass some parameter into URL including acceptFileType to A) to filter file upload.

On B: I pass http://www.urlofA.com/Home/Upload?acceptFileTypes="image/*, application/pdf"

On A:
In controller:

```
public ActionResult Upload(string path, string acceptFileTypes = "*/*", bool dialog = true)
{            
    ViewBag.AcceptFileTypes = acceptFileTypes;            
    return View();
}
```

In Upload.chtml:

```
<input type="file" accept=@ViewBag.AcceptFileType"/>
```

When I click "Ok" button, I validate the file is valid to make sure only type which accepted is must be uploaded, because user can change view file in dialog choose file and get other one. I check it by regular expression.

```
this.acceptType.test(file.type) && this.acceptType.test(file.name)
```

This regular expression I define on A:

```
$('#file').fileUpload{
    acceptType: /(\.|\/)(pdf|gif|jpe?g|png|bmp)$/i
}
```

Currently, I just pass acceptFileType to handle in UI, I cannot pass acceptType to validate in js.

I try to pass acceptType into url, and I got "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: @Hatsjoem: the A site is dummy, it just handle the upload file. The B must be pass file type to make it filter. My business required it.

Comment: Don't do this. Since it's passed in from the client, your user can just change the regular expression. This sort of thing leads to gaping security holes. Find a better solution.

Comment: @AntP exactly what I thought

Comment: May you say more about this? I know, but I define any regular expression base on my job, site A is not on it's purpuse.

Comment: There isn't much more to say - you need to stop doing this and configure the accepted filetypes directly in application A (server-side). Otherwise, I can just change the regex that's passed into the iframe and upload whatever the hell I want. Or I can just call the controller action myself.

Comment: Unless you're already restricting it server-side in A and this is just for controlling the dialog options, in which case it's not so much of an issue.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, maybe I have only solution is: define a little bit bl on site A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AntP said, it will have a big gap security in my application. I will change my business logic a little bit, move something from business to site. I will make this as an answer. Thank AntP

Answer (score 0):

use this code to validate your file

var ext = $('#my_file_field').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

if($.inArray(ext, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1) {

```
alert('invalid extension!');
```

}